# ORA-06502 while dbms_sql.execute(<anonymous block>) with out-binding

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, dynamic-sql

I got some trouble with executing dynamic SQL with binding variables (in and out) via dbms_sql.
I always get an ORA-06502 but cannot get the reason.
I could reduce the SQL-snippet so far to know that the out parameter occurs the error.

```
declare
  l_cur_id NUMBER;
  l_sql    VARCHAR2(100) := 'begin :1 := ''test''; end;';
  l_res    VARCHAR2(100);
  l_dbms   NUMBER;
begin
  l_cur_id := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse(l_cur_id, l_sql, dbms_sql.native);
  dbms_sql.bind_variable(l_cur_id, '1', l_res);
  l_dbms := dbms_sql.execute(l_cur_id); -- ORA here
  dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_cur_id);
exception
  when others then
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_cur_id);
    raise;
end;
/
```

In-parameters work fine.
I'm using Oracle Database 12 Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0

Do I have to config the out-parameter in another way?
I'm thankful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified a size for the bind variable. By default it uses the current length of the variable; [from the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-D3067451-82DA-4303-AC09-4737B5A89007):

> | Parameter | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | `out_value_size` | Maximum expected OUT value size, in bytes, for the VARCHAR2, RAW, CHAR OUT or IN/OUT variable. If no size is given, then the length of the current value is used. This parameter must be specified if the value parameter is not initialized. |

As that variable is by default initialised as null, that length is zero; which is the same as saying it isn't initialised. So it errors when it tries to assign the four-character `'test'` to to the zero-character variable.

You also [need to call `dbms_sql.variable_value`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-8030A105-8506-4AC0-888A-1C13A5DE2CDF) to get retrieve the out bind variable value.

If you initialised `l_res` with a value *at least* as long as anything you might assign inside the dynamic block then it would work:

```
declare
  ...
  l_res    VARCHAR2(100) := 'xxxx';
  ...
begin
  ...
  dbms_sql.bind_variable(l_cur_id, '1', l_res);
  l_dbms := dbms_sql.execute(l_cur_id);
  dbms_sql.variable_value(l_cur_id, '1', l_res);
  ...
end;
/
```

but that obviously ideal, as really you'd need to supply a value 100-chars long, and remember to adjust that if the length changed later; so instead specify the length in the bind call:

```
declare
  ...
  l_res    VARCHAR2(100);
  ...
begin
  ...
  dbms_sql.bind_variable(l_cur_id, '1', l_res, 100);
  l_dbms := dbms_sql.execute(l_cur_id);
  dbms_sql.variable_value(l_cur_id, '1', l_res);
  ...
end;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b3d877017ca0d7b563500fcc87258abd)

Comment: Hi Alex,
I tried both. The error doesn't occur any more, thanks :)
But in both cases, `l_res`' value does not change (so it's `null` or `'xxxx'`).

Comment: @StefanWarminski - you were missing the `variable_value` call - updated answer and db<>fiddle.